# Windows AWS EC2 no Display when not Connected

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, virtualbox

I have a VirtualBox VM with a startup script to run GUI tests (button clicks etc) on my application. This works fine.

I cloned this image and imported it to AWS and launched an EC2. When this same script runs on the EC2, it seems like the screen is either a different resolution or doesn't exist at all. All the tests fail as if the windows are not on the screen and if I add something to the script to take a screenshot, it bombs.

If I RDP into the machine while the script runs, everything is fine.

What is different about this AWS VM that causes the display to not stick/exist unless I am logged in and is there a way to change this?

Comment: You can actually ask the infrastructure to take a [screenshot](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/05/ec2-now-supports-the-ability-to-capture-screenshots-of-an-instance-console/) of a Windows instance.  This might get you started troubleshooting... I don't know.

Comment: good thought, but it just shows the lock screen whether I am logged in or not